# Did Yoda have a ship on Dagobah to leave the system?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In the original trilogy of *Star Wars*, I never saw Yoda's ship (and, an Astromech to handle the ship, but it may not have been necessary). Was his ship intact? Or, was his ship sunk down deep out from his *force sense*? Or, did he need to make a holographic call to Bail Organa when he needed to leave the system (it's also a possibility that it was Bail Organa who dropped Yoda on Dagobah, assuming he could land his ship safely on Dagobah)? Or, was he stuck there permanently?

Anything from the canon? You can use the Old canon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this deleted scene from Episode 3, you can see that Yoda landed on Dagobah in an evacuation pod. The "[Star Wars: Complete Cross-Sections](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Cross-Sections)" describes it as an [E3-Standard Lifeboat](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/E3-standard_starship_lifeboat) that was dropped from Bail Organa's ship.

The [Star Wars Databank](http://web.archive.org/web/20100306102647/http://www.starwars.com/databank/starship/yodaescapepod/index.html) described it thusly;

> *Having failed to stop the Emperor and realizing that the galaxy had
>   grown to be a dark and deadly place for any surviving Jedi, **the
>   revered Master Yoda fled into exile at the tragic end of the Clone
>   Wars. Aboard a star-shaped escape pod [a 3.5 meter diameter E3-standard starship lifeboat E], he journeyed to the obscure
>   world of Dagobah.** As the pod settled down on the marshy surface of the
>   shrouded bog planet, its hatch opened and Yoda surveyed the grim
>   surroundings. This would be his home for over two decades.*

---

The pod was not capable of interstellar flight (or reaching orbit from the ground) which means that Yoda was effectively stranded although it's reasonable to assume that the lifeboat contained some kind of transmitter or emergency beacon, allowing him to be rescued the surface, should the need arise.

Comment: From the Wikia page, the pod had one-trip warp capability and it was destroyed by natural elements of Dagobah (you may add these to answer). But, could he still leave the system?

Comment: nice one Richard im at top vote for the day. You get my upvote as soon as the day is over on this site ... wich is in about 2 hours ;)

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I've restricted myself only to canon or recently-canon sources. The wikia is referencing various EU novels of dubious canon status.